# python: shlex splitting

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I would like to split a string using `shlex` (because I have to preserve text in quotes), but I do not want it to split over dots.

My code is the following:

```
import shlex
my_splitter = shlex.shlex('''foo, bar, "one, two", three four, 2.15''', posix=True)
my_splitter.whitespace += ','
my_splitter.whitespace_split = True
print(list(my_splitter))
```

output

```
['foo', 'bar', 'one, two', 'three', 'four', '2', '.', '15']
```

I do not want it to split `'2.15'` into `'2','.','15'`

Comment: Can you precise the command you use for splitting?

Comment: it is `whitespace_split`

Comment: Odd, I didn't think it would split like that. I would recommend trying the CSV parser instead as that look near enough to CSV.

Comment: See [Python 2 demo](https://rextester.com/FIQO15674), your code works. Same in [Python 3](https://ideone.com/PkIge4).

Comment: what is the csv parser? I have used numpy.gentotxt but it does not work because there are some items that have double quotes

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you are right, but it does not work on my system, I can't figure out why

Comment: Use the CSV module as shown in the linked thread.